Max of a 2 variable function on a compact set
Let $f$ be a real differentiable function defined on $[0,1]$ s.t.

$f(0)=1,\ f(1)=0$
$f$ decreasing

We call $G$ the following function defined on $S = [0,1] \times [0,1]$:
$$
G(x,y) = (f(x)-x f'(x)) (f(y) - y f'(y)) - 2 x y f'(x) f'(y)
$$
My conjecture is: the maximum of $G$ is always reached on the boundary of $S$.
I plotted several examples of $G$ and it always seems to be true. Any idea on how to prove this property?
Thanks, Nicola

To clarify: by "$f$ decreasing", do you mean that $f$ is strictly decreasing, or that $f$ is non-increasing?  For $x<y$, is it always true that $f(x)>f(y)$ or could $f(x)=f(y)$?

Non-increasing. But if someone can prove it for the functions that are strictly decreasing, I’m still interested.

I'm not sure.  For $f(x)=1-x^n$, both partials are zero at $x=y=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n-1}{n^2+2n-1}}$.  Although, it looks like $G$ achieves the same value (max?) on the boundary at $x=0$, $y=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n-1}{n^2+2n-1}}$ and $x=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n-1}{n^2+2n-1}}$, $y=0$.

Hello. Thanks for the suggestion. I tested 1-x^n for n=3, 4, 5 and the max is clearly on the boundary, as you can easily check plotting G. Anyway, even if the same value was reached even inside S (and I don't think this happens with 1-x^n) this is still not a counter-example. My conjecture is that the max is reached on the boundary but I don't say that it is reached ONLY on the boundary.

I never said it was a counterexample.  That's why I just mentioned it in the comments.  It's pretty straightforward to take the partials and set them to zero.  I checked it twice, so I think my math is correct.  Anyway, it's not a counterexample.  Possibly modifying it will give a counterexample.  Hope you get an answer, since it's an interesting question IMO.
